# How can I make a mock DB to be pulled into Alteryx?

Tags: xml, database, alteryx

I am working on a school project and am having some issue figuring this out. My team and I's problem is that we have 24 XML files from our sponsor (they make custom garage doors), and it is unstructured data that needs to be organized to be able to determine trends, patterns, etc. We need help on figuring out how to create a mock database for those 24 files so Alteryx can pull from the DB instead of entering each file individually, (since the sponsor has millions of files it wouldn't work to enter each individually).

The sponsor's current situation is that they pull text files from an Oracle DB that are made into XML files when extracted. My team doesn't have access to the Oracle DB so we need to make a mock DB (doesn't have to be Oracle) that will mimic this to show how Alteryx can structure the unstructured data.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Millions of files?  Is this a one time thing?  If so, you're going to have to deal with those one way or the other.  If you can import them into Alteryx then do it and save yourself the hassle of transforming the data for a database.

Comment: This is a prototype, so those 24 files represent the millions of files, so I can't upload all 24 manually because the sponsor obviously won't want to do that. Our professor basically wants a prototype that can represent what implementation might look like.